# How to migrate comma seperate values in different rows of DB using TALEND

Tags: data-migration, talend

In my old DB, i have 2 columns in one of the table which are having comma seperated values like

```
oid      columnA         columnB   
  1         21,22          hi,hello
```

Now i want to migrate this value in my new table as

```
NEW_OID   old_oid     ID     COMMENTS
1            1        21         hi
2            1        22         hello
```

I tried using tNormalize component but it allowed to migrate only one comma delimmted column like either i can migrate ColumnA or COlumnB but not both. Using this i am getting output as

```
NEW_OID   old_oid     ID     COMMENTS
1            1        21         hi,hello
2            1        22         hi,hello
```

Someone please guide me how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

```
One possible way is that you have to take two pipelines of your flow - as below
tInput-->tNormalize(Normalize on ID column) -->tMap-->(add rownumber column here)-->tHash1/tFile1
tInput-->tNormalize(Normalize on comments) -->tMap-->(add rownumber column here)-->tHash2/tFile2

tHash/tFile1-----tMap (tHash2/tFile2) Join on new oid, oldoid and rownumber -->output
```

Comment: there are no tHash/tFile1 components in palette. Could you please tell me are these compnonets or something else.

Comment: with tHash i meant tHashOutput/tHashInput and tFile i meant tFileInputdelimited/tFileOutputdelimited...dont worry about components, you can use any component..in above approach i am suggesting them to be used only for keeping data to be used further in tmap for join..